# How can I vertically align the labels in a tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

---

I have drawn the above diagram with diagonal arrows in TikZ, but the labels look like they have been placed on a curve instead of next to each other. I think I understand why they are placed like that: TikZ puts the labels in the middle of the arrows and the diagonal arrows end slightly lower. But I'm unable to fix this.

The code I have written for this diagram is:

```
\documentclass[border=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
  arr/.style={->,font=\scriptsize},
  description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}
]
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=4em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex
] 
{A[f]_0:=A & A[f]_1 & A[f]_2 & \cdots \\
                    &        & B      \\};
\draw[arr] (m-1-1) -- node[above]       {$\pi_0$}  (m-1-2); 
\draw[arr] (m-1-1) -- node[description] {$f_0:=f$} (m-2-3);
\draw[arr] (m-1-2) -- node[above]       {$\pi_1$}  (m-1-3);
\draw[arr] (m-1-2) -- node[description] {$f_1$}    (m-2-3);
\draw[arr] (m-1-3) -- node[above]       {$\pi_2$}  (m-1-4);
\draw[arr] (m-1-3) -- node[description] {$f_2$}    (m-2-3);
\draw[arr] (m-1-4) -- node[description] {$f_3$}    (m-2-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So the question is: how can I put the labels `$f_0:=f$`, `$f_1$`, `$f_2$` and `$f_3$` at the same height, preferably the height of `$f_2$`?

Comment: a very ugly hack is to tweak the positions manually, using something like `node[description,pos=0.4]...` I'm sure one of the gurus will have a better method, but at least this gives you something :)

Comment: @cmhughes: How will I be able to determine the right number to give to pos? It seems unlikely that this is going to be very precise...

Comment: that's why I said it was an ugly hack :)

Comment: You can place the label you prefer ($f_2$?) like you did and place other nodes over intersections of an horizontal line through f_2 and arrows. Not so easy like your solution but possible.

Comment: That sounds like a solution. But I'm not sure how to do that. Could you give an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I told you in my comment you need to set an horizontal line. I selected `f_2` as a reference point and named it while placing on the path

```
\draw[arr] (m-1-3) -- node[description] (f2) {$f_2$} (m-2-3)
```

the horizontal line crossing `f2` is declared with

```
\path[name path=pf2] (m-1-1|-f2)--(m-1-4|-f2);
```

Then you need to `name` all other paths like

```
\draw[arr,name path=pf0] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-3);
```

and place labels over intersections

```
\node[arr,description,name intersections={of=pf0 and pf2}] (f0) at (intersection-1) {$f_0:=f$};
```

My complete code is

```
\documentclass[border=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[
  arr/.style={->,font=\scriptsize},
  description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}
]
\matrix (m) [
  matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=4em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex
] 
{A[f]_0:=A & A[f]_1 & A[f]_2 & \cdots \\
                    &        & B      \\};
\draw[arr] (m-1-1) -- node[above]       {$\pi_0$}  (m-1-2); 
\draw[arr] (m-1-2) -- node[above]       {$\pi_1$}  (m-1-3);
\draw[arr] (m-1-3) -- node[above]       {$\pi_2$}  (m-1-4);

\draw[arr] (m-1-3) -- node[description] (f2) {$f_2$}    (m-2-3);
\draw[arr,name path=pf0] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-3);
\draw[arr,name path=pf1] (m-1-2) -- (m-2-3);
\draw[arr,name path=pf3] (m-1-4) -- (m-2-3);
\path[name path=pf2] (m-1-1|-f2)--(m-1-4|-f2);
\draw[red] (m-1-1|-f2)--(m-1-4|-f2);

\node[arr,description,name intersections={of=pf0 and pf2}] (f0) at (intersection-1) {$f_0:=f$};
\node[arr,description,name intersections={of=pf1 and pf2}] (f1) at (intersection-1) {$f_1$};
\node[arr,description,name intersections={of=pf3 and pf2}] (f3) at (intersection-1) {$f_3$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and the result

[image]

Comment: This looks very nice, great solution!